# Error: Could not find or load main class in maven project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am facing a strange issue.I am getting " Error: Could not find or load main class " in basic hello world program in my maven project whenever I've add **selenium 3x jar** files in pom.xml
There is no such issue in 2.53 selenium jar files or adding any other dependencies. This issue occurs only with adding this specific jar only. I'am using Eclipse (Oxygen) march version. Java version in system"1.8.0_102"

```
public class hello2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

My maven dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

[problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieO7e.png)

Comment: Is there an error message/stack trace?  Off the top of my head, perhaps you have a versioning issue with some other dependency, except you are forcing versions in your POM.

Comment: Would you mind to post your entire pom?

Comment: i have already posted entire pom..please read it properly @vatbub

Comment: Got to project right click on maven n update maven project

Comment: already update.clean install test.everything tried

Comment: Please create new workspace with new mavenproject n then check if you are getting same

Comment: yes. me getting same error with selenium 3x jar only

Comment: If you comment selenium dependence still you are getting error ?.. my suggestion would be upgraded your   eclipse to neno .3 version

Comment: i have added a picture regarding problems

Comment: Navigate to commons-lang3-3.5.jar and remove it then update the project

Comment: Well, your pom looked too tiny to me :P Usually, you need to tell maven that if should write the name of the main class file to the jar's manifest. And your pom does not tell maven to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your question why you need **selenium 3x jars** as your code doesn't require any *selenium jar*. Moreover, the errors in details would have helped us to debug your issue in a better way.

However, **2** (two) issues are pretty evident as follows :

- You are using **JDK 1.8.0_102** which is pretty ancient.
- You are using **org.seleniumhq.selenium v 3.5.3** which is pretty old.
- From the snapshot it seems possibly the **.m2/repository** have got corrupted due to presence of multiple jars from **Selenium 2.53** and **Selenium 3.5.3** repository.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u171**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- If you don't have any dependency on *Selenium* remove the *selenium jar* dependency completely.
- If you have a dependency on *Selenium* add the latest *selenium* dependency as follows :

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- If the **.m2/repository** have got corrupted *delete* the **.m2** sub-directory completely.
- From the console execute : `mvn clean` (to flush out previous dependencies)
- From the console execute : `mvn install` (to install the necessary dependencies)
- From the console execute : `mvn test` (to execute your program)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the actual cause of the issue, but for maven to add the information about the main class to the jar's manifest, you must tell maven explicitly to do so. I use the `maven-assembly-plugin` for that. It packages all dependencies and my code into one runnable jar:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                <mainClass>com.example.package.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```